# Trouble with SVN Add and German Umlaut

Tags: svn, encoding

I wrote a batch file to add and commit files to my SVN repository:

```
cd "C:\Users\User\Desktop"
for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i in (`svn status ^| findstr /r "^\?"`) do svn add "%%i %%j"
for /f "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i in (`svn status ^| findstr /r "^\!"`) do svn delete "%%i %%j"
svn commit -m "Commit via Batch"
```

Unfortunately, I am getting into trouble with the German Umlaut:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>svn add "SS06_Haupt_mit L÷sung.pdf"
svn: warning: W155010: 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\SS06_Haupt_mit L÷sung.pdf' not
 found
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

Is there a Workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set an other codepage at the top of the batch file:

```
chcp 1252
```